# select children categories in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a nested categories. this is structure.

```
CREATE TABLE 'category' (
  'id' INT,
  'title' VARCHAR(50),
  'category_id' INT,
)
```

relation is simple

(id, parent id)

```
main (1, NULL)
--parent (2, 1)
----child1 (3, 2)
----child2 (4, 2)
--foo (5, 1)
----baz (6, 5)
--bar (7, 1)
```

I want to select category's childrens (MYSQL)

for "parent" category it is "child1" and "child2"

for "main" category it is:

```
--parent (2, 1)
----child1 (3, 2)
----child2 (4, 2)
--foo (5, 1)
----baz (6, 5)
--bar (7, 1)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that with this scheme you cannot perform the select with only one request. But this [article](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602536/mysql-nested-sets-how-to-find-parent-of-node) may help.

Edit: I've found that [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Trees_in_SQL_databases.aspx) on code projects that looks like your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a limit on the number of levels it's no problem, just write down a query that selects children for each level. it will look something like this:

```
SELECT *....
    FROM category AS level1
    LEFT JOIN category AS level2 ON (c2.category_id = c1.id)
    LEFT JOIN category AS level3 ON (c3.category_id = c2.id)
    ...
WHERE c1.category_id = 0
```

if you have no limit on the number of children you can:

1. write a mysql recursive function
2. fetch all mysql data and make the parent/children matching under the prog. language (ie php)
3. save somewhere (if you have a config table somewhere) the number of levels yo u have, and implement a query string generator that creates the query string for a given number of levels. on each update/insert you should check if the number of levels is changed and store it