# Hierarchy/Tree Data - Finding origin

Tags: php, mysql, loops, database-design, hierarchical-data

Imagine a tree. I would like to trace back to the trunk of the tree given any branch on that tree, with the number of branches within branches being unlimited. There are no many-to-many connections.

I am logging customers and have set up a table to show which existing customer recommended a new customer to us, so this has spread out to somewhat of a "family tree".

Every time a new customer comes on board, I need to know the original customer at the origin of the tree that started everything.

Here is a mock-up of my table to show 2 "families", with 1 and 11 being the top of the tree for each. Each parent has 2 children in this example and each number is a foreign key for a customer's contract number.

```
parents children
1       2
1       3
2       4
2       5
3       6
3       7
11      12
11      13
12      14
12      15
13      16
13      17
```

So far, I have been using MySQL and a PHP loop to SELECT a parent WHERE the child has a specific contract number, then looking to see if that parent is a child itself in the same table. I keep this loop going until no rows are returned and I get the answer.

My question is, is this the most efficient way to do this, or is there a solution outside of PHP, or by redesigning the table? I can see there being hundreds of "generations" soon and I don't want it to start getting too slow.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [Nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). It allows to store hierarchical data in a relational database.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602566/519020), it will give you the idea of how to find the `origin` of any record.

Comment: The nested set model deserves to be looked at whenever tree traversal operations are more speed critical than updates.  The article you referenced is a good summary.

Answer (score 0):

Bill Karwin made a nice slideshow called [SQL Antipatterns Strike Back](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back).  The topic turns to techniques for handling trees starting at slide 48.

Personally, I like the closure table technique.  It's easy to query, efficient and with the right triggers, it's maintenance-free.